# DependencyProperty not update

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties

I have a user control with IsChecked Property

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsCheckedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "IsChecked", typeof(bool), typeof(LabeledCheckbox),new FrameworkPropertyMetadata
    {
        DefaultValue = false,
        BindsTwoWayByDefault = true,

    });

    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get { return (bool)this.GetValue(IsCheckedProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(IsCheckedProperty, value); }
    }
```

I'm bounding the IsChecked Property to a another property called active
and i create a checkbox that the IsChecked Property also bound to the active property

```
<controls:LabeledCheckbox x:Name="ccc" Tag="Active" CheckedColor=" #33cc00" UncheckedColor="#cc2900" CheckedContent="hello" UncheckedContent="world" IsChecked="{Binding Active, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" FontSize="25" Margin="5" Width="100"/>
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Active, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

The checkbox is update correctly but the controls:LabeledCheckbox not update
the other DP in controls:LabeledCheckbox  are working great.

why the IsChecked property not updating?
tried to use RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}
on the controls:LabeledCheckbox like this:

```
<controls:LabeledCheckbox x:Name="ccc" Tag="Active" CheckedColor=" #33cc00" UncheckedColor="#cc2900" CheckedContent="שלום" UncheckedContent="עולם" IsChecked="{Binding Active, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" FontSize="25" Margin="5" Width="100"/>
```

tried one way to source

the set of IsChecked never triggered unless i set True ao false directly and not binding.

**UPDATE**
Adding the UserControl's full code:

```
public partial class LabeledCheckbox : UserControl
{
    public LabeledCheckbox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsCheckedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "IsChecked", typeof(bool), typeof(LabeledCheckbox),new FrameworkPropertyMetadata
    {
        DefaultValue = false,
        BindsTwoWayByDefault = true,
        PropertyChangedCallback = CheckChanged

    });

    private static void CheckChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Change");
    }

    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get { return (bool)this.GetValue(IsCheckedProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(IsCheckedProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CheckedColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "CheckedColor", typeof(Color), typeof(LabeledCheckbox), new PropertyMetadata(Colors.White));

    public Color CheckedColor
    {
        get { return (Color)this.GetValue(CheckedColorProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(CheckedColorProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CheckedContentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "CheckedContent", typeof(string), typeof(LabeledCheckbox), null);

    public string CheckedContent
    {
        get { return (string)this.GetValue(CheckedContentProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(CheckedContentProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty UncheckedColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "UncheckedColor", typeof(Color), typeof(LabeledCheckbox), new PropertyMetadata(Colors.White));

    public Color UncheckedColor
    {
        get { return (Color)this.GetValue(UncheckedColorProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(UncheckedColorProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty UncheckedContentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "UncheckedContent", typeof(string), typeof(LabeledCheckbox), null);

    public string UncheckedContent
    {
        get { return (string)this.GetValue(UncheckedContentProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(UncheckedContentProperty, value); }
    }


    public static readonly RoutedEvent CheckedChangeEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("CheckedChange", RoutingStrategy.Direct, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(LabeledCheckbox));

    public event RoutedEventHandler CheckedChange
    {
        add { AddHandler(CheckedChangeEvent, value); }
        remove { RemoveHandler(CheckedChangeEvent, value); }
    }

    private void ToggleCheckbox(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        IsChecked = !IsChecked;
        AnimateCheckbox();
        RaiseCheckedChangeEvent();
    }

    private void AnimateCheckbox()
    {
        DoubleAnimation cAnim = null;
        DoubleAnimation ucAnim = null;
        if (IsChecked)
        {
            cAnim = AnimationsHandler.AnimateElementWidth(0, this.Width, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(400));
            ucAnim = AnimationsHandler.AnimateElementWidth(this.Width, 0, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(400));
        }
        else
        {
            cAnim = AnimationsHandler.AnimateElementWidth(this.Width, 0, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(400));
            ucAnim = AnimationsHandler.AnimateElementWidth(0, this.Width, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(400));
        }
        var sb = new Storyboard();
        AnimationsHandler.AddToStoryboard(sb, cAnim, check, new PropertyPath(FrameworkElement.WidthProperty));
        AnimationsHandler.AddToStoryboard(sb, ucAnim, uncheck, new PropertyPath(FrameworkElement.WidthProperty));
        sb.Begin();
    }

    void RaiseCheckedChangeEvent()
    {
        RoutedEventArgs newEventArgs = new RoutedEventArgs(LabeledCheckbox.CheckedChangeEvent);
        RaiseEvent(newEventArgs);
    }

    private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ToggleCheckbox(null, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: When the property value is set by a Binding (and some other sources) WPF bypasses the setter of the CLR property wrapper and directly calls SetValue. You should register a PropertyChangedCallback with property metadata.

Comment: How do you confirm that the dependency property is not being set?

Comment: I tried PropertyChangedCallback but it doesn't firing

Comment: Also make sure you don't have something like `DataContext = this` in your UserControl.

Comment: It isn't firing when you check the Checkbox?

Comment: I tried PropertyChangedCallback  without the DataContext = this or something like that, I've added the full code of the user control

Comment: Clemens, you were right i just needed to restart Visual Studio and it worked thank you